# How to use Post method in Angular to get

Tags: angularjs, http, spring-mvc

> Unable to insert data into database using mysql anglerJS and Spring controller. Giving 400 error. Tried to google it, but not get the code.So where I am committing mistake

Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/insert",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Emp insret(@RequestParam(value="user")String 
user,@RequestParam(value="pass1")String pass)
{
     Emp em=new Emp();
     em.setUser(user);
     em.setPass(pass);
     System.out.println(user+""+pass);
     return er.save(em);

}
```

Angular file for post method

script1.js

```
   var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
        .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $log) {

            $scope.abc = function () {
                $log.info($scope.user)
                $log.info($scope.pass1)// you will have your updated value here
                $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:     '/insert',

                data : {
                    'user' : $scope.user,
                    'pass':$scope.pass1
                },
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                 $scope.repos = response.data;
                 $log.info(response);
             });
        }
});
```

Embedded angular in the HTML file for post method.

index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js">
    </script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="script1.js"></script>
        </head>
          <body ng-app="myApp" >
            <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
               <form ng-submit="abc()">
                  <input type="text"  ng-model="user" />
                  <input type="text"  ng-model="pass1" />
                  <button type="submit">Test</button>
               </form>
            </div>
          </body>
      </html>
```

If I use its inserting data with this URL localhost:8080/insert.But if i use 
 angular its 400 error`

```
`@RequestMapping(value="/insert")
  public Emp insret() 
 {
  Emp em=new Emp(); 
  em.setUser("etc"); 
  em.setPass("1234"); return er.save(em); 
 }
```

Comment: Was just wondering, have you tried 'application/json' as content-type?

Comment: POST http://localhost:8080/insert 400 () this error i am getting when I use 'application/json'

Comment: no web context path?

Comment: If server accept `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, have you tried to serialize the `data`? Such as using `data: $.param({user: $scope.user, pass: $scope.pass1})`.

Comment: @shaochuancs I tried its not inserting

Comment: @ShreenivasKulkarni Does it still return 400 error?

Comment: Yes still its 400

Comment: @ShreenivasKulkarni Well, I suggest checking server side code/log, to see why it is 400.

Comment: @shaochuancs if I use @RequestMapping(value="/insert")
public Emp insret()
{
     Emp em=new Emp();
     em.setUser("etc");
     em.setPass("1234");
     return er.save(em);

} with http://localhost:8080/insert . It's working .But if i use angular its 400 error.

Comment: @ShreenivasKulkarni Can you put related code in the question? It's more readable. Also, have you found why it's 400? Any wrong HTTP request format?

Comment: @shaochuancs I inserted in question

Comment: Use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam` and change the content type to `application/json`

Comment: @akuma8 Thank you so much its working ..

Comment: I add some additionnal explanation so you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formal answer :

```
@PostMapping(value="/insert",produces="application/json")
public Emp insret(@RequestBody Emp em){
 //do ....
 return er.save(em);
}
```

When you post data from Angular or other client, these data are in the request's body that why Spring guys introduce this annotation.

`@RequestParam` is for retrieving request parameters values which in your case, would like : `/insert?user=value1&pass1=value2` and this is not what you want.